# Neural Networks Overfitting with Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to model a network that takes in 90 parameters and give an integer between 1 and 6 inclusive.
Below is my scaled model that `i` intend to begin with and I appreciate any corrections or directions

```
self.model = keras.Sequential()
self.model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(None, 90)))
self.model.add(Activation(activation="relu"))
self.model.add(LSTM(50))
self.model.add(Activation(activation="relu"))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.01))
self.model.add(Dense(7,  activation="softmax"))

self.train_epoch = 6000
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.000002)
self.model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,  metrics=['accuracy'])
info = self.model.fit(self.x, self.y, epochs=self.train_epoch, validation_data=(self.m, self.n),  shuffle=True )
```

The issue comes in that my validation loss keeps increasing after some time.
I have tried small learning rates, high dropout value and even increased number of layers.
Can Someone please advise me on what I'm doing wrong.

I'm also not sure how many layers to use or nodes per each layer to achieve accuracy values greater than 0.5.

If someone can help I will give a link to the data and see if they can achieve better results.

Heres my current graph.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HcPn.png)

Comment: Why is it a problem that the validation loss keeps decreasing? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Why do you have 7 units in the output `Dense` layer if you want the output to be in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`? It's 6 possible values...

Comment: It gives an error indicating that it recieved a value outside the accepted range of (0,6)

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you keep training for a long time, validation error will eventually increase. 
As you mentioned in the title, it's a common result of over-fitting. And that's why you are checking validation error (to detect over-fitting and terminate the training), as well as training error. 
You can monitor validation loss yourself, but also you can use [early stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping).

The way to apply early stopping in Keras is introduced at: 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-stop-training-deep-neural-networks-at-the-right-time-using-early-stopping/

And please note that LSTM is used for time-series data (`keras.**Sequential**()`).

Answer (score 0):

Your statement and the graph are contradicting. When you experience overfitting always decrease the number of parameters of the model(i.e layers/kernels). Try training fewer epochs. You seem to be increasing them. Besides your chance-level is 1/7 and not 1/2. I believe its a 7 class problem.